# How to verify the actual WriteConcern the mongo server side received

Tags: mongodb

In my application, I allow the client app to specify the WriteConcern value when it make a query via the MongoDB C# driver.
Now, to test my code, I want to check and confirm from the MongoDB server side that it does receive the WriteConcern value as the client app specified.
I tried both db.setProfilingLevel(2) and set the mongod logging level to verbose level 5. But neither of them works. Both provides more detailed info about the query it received and some metrics info like response time etc. But still no clue about the WriteConcern it received.
Any idea?

Comment: What are you expecting to see? Just an indication of the `w` value that was set clientside? I think this should be in the logs, actually. You could test the write concern by, for example, having less nodes available than the value of `w`, making the operations block while waiting for enough nodes to come online.